# Find line which contains given word and return substring

Tags: php

I have file with lines which look like  **word_1:word_2**
(for example file looks like

```
username:test
password:test_pass
dir:root
```

)

. How to find from file word_2 when I have word_1 ? Is there in PHP contains and substring like in Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont describe your file format very well, but maybe its formatted like a csv-file

```
$file = fopen('filename', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1024, ':')) !== false) {
  if (in_array($needle, $line)) {
    return $line;
  }
}
return null;
```

If you assume, that you are always looking for the first field, you can replace `in_array(/* .. */)` with `$line[0] === $needle`.

Update: After the edit of the question, I would suggest something like this, as it seems, that the file is just a kind of csv file (with ":" instead of ",").

```
function getValue ($key, $filename) {
  $file = fopen('filename', 'r');
  while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1024, ':')) !== false) {
    if ($line[0] === $key) {
      fclose($file);
      return $line[1];
    }
  }
  fclose($file);
  return null;
}
```

Also consider reading the file once and then just access the values

```
class MyClass {
  private $data = array();
  public function __construct ($filename) {
    $file = fopen('filename', 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1024, ':')) !== false) {
      $this->data[$line[0]] = $line[1];
    }
    fclose($file);
  }
  function getValue ($key, $filename) {
    return array_key_exists($key, $this->data)
           ? $this->data[$key];
           : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To find out if a string contains another string, use [strpos()](http://nl.php.net/strpos)

Note that you need the `!==` when using the `strpos()` function because of the fact that if the string starts with the string you are looking for, it will return 0 which is the same as false.

```
if(strpos($mystring, 'word_1') !== false)
{
    //$mystring contains word_1
}
```

And I would use the [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string and get the second part.

Comment: It seems, that you can test against `=== 0` directly. Also you should (at least) include the `:` to avoid, that for example `$mystring = 'rd:te';` matches.

Comment: My sollution is more general, because it tests whether the string is contained withing another string, not only if it starts with the string. And I don't understand your second address.

Comment: With `$mystring = 'rd:te'`, `strpos($mystring, 'password:test_pass')` (see the second line of the example above) will return `!== false`. However, I dont think, that the most generic solution is always also the better solution.

Comment: I didn't say it was the best solution, but it addressed the question of the contains function he was looking for.